# Node.js webpack5 error, Module not found; BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm constantly getting this error message and don't have a clue how to solve it:

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is Webpack v5 no longer adds polyfills for Node.js built-ins and you should choose between:

- install polyfills and resolve them; or
- turn them off using new Webpack API.

If you choose the second option, use the [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer I’m working on, it will fix all the things for you with help of [`@putout/plugin-webpack`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/plugin-webpack#readme). Here is what it looks like:

`convert-node-to-resolve-fallback` fixes webpack compilation error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'`

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

Incorrect code:

```js
module.exports = {
    node: {
        path: 'empty',
        buffer: 'empty',
        crypto: 'empty'
    },
};
```

Correct code:

```js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            path: false,
            buffer: false,
            crypto: false
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Where should I put this in my code?

Comment: To your webpack.config.js

Comment: I've put it like this and still not working:

Comment: Could you please show your config?

Comment: I don't know gow to put pictures in comments to show you my error and config... all I have in config is code you gave me.

Comment: Just updated examples, do you have any error after that? Is it the same? You can add new information into your question.

Answer (score 3):

The issue for me was that vscode automatically imported a library while I was coding: "firestore" and it was causing a whole heap of errors, look out for any unused or unintentional imports.

Answer (score -1):

Installing the latest version of Node(Node v18.4.0 at the time) resolved the issue for me without having to perform any extra actions like installing and resolving polyfills.